# Traefik responds 404 when using behind AWS NLB TLS listener

Tags: amazon-web-services, http-status-code-404, traefik, k3s, nlb

I have a k3s cluster setup with Traefik v2.8.5 and want to use AWS NLB in front of it to handle the  TLS. As it is meant to be an internal cluster the DNS records are kept in a Route53 private zone with a alias to the cluster IP.

AWS NLB is configured with two listeners: TCP for port 80 and TLS for port 443. Both listeners have TargetGroups which contain the cluster EC2 instances.

The test container deployment is relatively simple:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: whoami
  labels:
    app: whoami
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: whoami
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: whoami
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: whoami
          image: traefik/whoami
          ports:
            - name: web
              containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  ports:
    - name: web
      port: 80
  selector:
    app: whoami
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`whoami.k3s.internal`)
      services:
        - name: whoami
          port: 80
  tls: {}
```

When I try to go `https://whoami.k3s.internal` it just responds with `404 page not found`. I can see from Traefik access logs that the request makes to Traefik, but does not have any other information:

```
172.19.128.11 - - [09/May/2023:18:27:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "-" 248 "-" "-" 0ms
```

When I test the IngressRoute without `tls: {}` and use http it works correctly:

```
172.19.128.11 - - [09/May/2023:18:22:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 805 "-" "-" 128 "default-whoami-ingress-293c8a11a84658abd910@kubernetescrd" "http://10.42.21.45:80" 2ms
```

The Traefik dashboard is accessible and HTTP routers and service in there seem to be correctly picked up.

Comment: Can you show the NLB setup or at least the target groups with any private info stripped out? Given the setup shown here I'm assuming you're terminating TLS at the NLB.

Comment: Your comment helped :). I rechecked all the configuration on AWS side, and turns out that I had created target groups with wrong protocol - TCP instead of TLS.